# Is there a way to access a variable from a .svelte file in the sibling .js file?

Tags: variables, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using svelte-geolocation in +layout.svelte to get the current position.

```html
<script>
    import styles from '../styles.css';
    import Navbar from './Navbar.svelte';
    import Footer from './Footer.svelte';
    export let data;

    import Geolocation from 'svelte-geolocation';

    let coords = [];
</script>

<Navbar />

<main>
    <Geolocation getPosition bind:coords />

    {coords}

    <slot />
    <p>{console.log(data)}</p>
</main>

<Footer />
```

In the +layout.js I'm making an API call to get weather data and I want to use the coords I'm getting in the +layout.svelte.

```js
import { PUBLIC_API_KEY } from '$env/static/public';

//coords are hardcoded for now
export async function load({ fetch }) {
  const weather_res = await fetch(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=53.994139&lon=-1.538713&units=imperial&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,alerts&appid=${PUBLIC_API_KEY}`
    );
    const weather_data = weather_res.json();

    return {
        weather_data
    };
}
```

Tried a couple of things but I'm new to Svelte and I ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the coordinates as either [route parameters](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing) or as URL query parameters.

In the former case they will be part of the `params` of the load event, in the latter case you get the values from the [`url.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).

To update the URL and trigger the `load` function again one can use [`goto`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto).